# Crud por consola pyton

Tags: python, pymysql

Estoy haciendo un *CRUD* en python haciendo todas las acciones por consola, estoy usando la librería `pymsql`, cuando ingreso la opción `1` el programa funciona correctamente, pero cuando ingreso la opción `2` el programa corre como si yo hubiese puesto el número `1`, como en python no hay `switch case` hice un `if/else` y no me funcionó, luego investigando encontré el *match case* que incorporaron a partir de la versión 3.10 y tampoco me funcionó, mi código.

```py
# Importar la librería de MYSQL
import pymysql as pym

    # Usar la librería y conectarse a la DB

try:
    conn = pym.connect(host='localhost', user='root',
                       password='', db='db_curso')
    print("************************************************************************")
    print("***** Menú para Insertar, Borrar, Actualizar y Consultar datos *********")
    print("************************************************************************")
    menu = ("""
            1 Para registrar/Ingresar un producto
            2 Para buscar un producto
            3 Para Eliminar un Producto
            4 Para editar un producto
        """)

    print(menu)
    opcion = int(input("Ingrese un número \n"))
    nombreProducto = str(input("Ingrese el nombre del producto \n"))
    descripcion = str(input("Ingrese la descripción del producto \n"))
    documentoUsuario = str(input("Ingrese el documento del usuario \n"))
    datos = [nombreProducto, descripcion, documentoUsuario]
    if opcion == 1:
            with conn.cursor() as cursor:
                insertar = "INSERT INTO tbl_producto(nombre_producto, descripcion, documento_usuario) VALUES ( %s, %s, %s)"
                #execute
                cursor.execute(insertar, datos)
                conn.commit()

    if opcion == 2:
            print(f"Digite el producto que quiere consultar {nombreProducto}")
            with conn.cursor() as cursor:

                consultar = "SELECT descripcion, documento_usuario FROM tbl_usuario where nombre_producto = %s"
                cursor.execute(opcion, (datos))
                documentos = cursor.fetchall
                for documento in documentos:
                    print(documento)
                    conn.close()

 
except (pym.err.OperationalError, pym.err.InternalError) as e:
    print("se presento el siguiente error", e)
```

Comment: En python no hay `switch`,  se usa `elif` no `else if`. Probaste eso? Otra cosa importante en python es mantener la indentación constante... y veo diferentes indentaciones en tu código!

Comment: Sí, si lo probé, pero no sé porqué no funciona

Comment: En primer lugar, no es necesario convertir a string el resultado de `input` pues esto ya te devuelve un string. Segundo, usa `elif` y no otro `if` para evaluar otro caso cuando el primer `if` falla, pues así te ahorras el volver a evaluar algo que ya cumplió una condición anterior. One Question!, al poner el `2` en el `input()` ves el mensaje del `print`??

Comment: Sí, lo hice con elif y sin embargo no funcionó, y cuando pongo la opción 2 no me sale nada, el código corre como si yo quisiera ingresar datos a la tabla

Comment: pon un `print(opcion)` y dime que sale

Comment: no sale nada, sigue apareciendo lo que digo, como si escribiese la opción 1

Comment: -_- pon eso abajo del `input` donde pides la opción

Comment: por eso -_- eso hice

Comment: abajo de la variable `datos`???. Si no te sale nada, entonces no tiene por qu ejecutarse ningún `if`

Comment: eso hice, cuando pongo la opcion 2 me sale literalmente el 2 y el código sigue como si hubiese ingresado la opción 1